# Databricks SparkR can't create spark DataFrame from large R data.frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks, sparkr

I have a local R data.frame with 16 Million records in databricks. When I try to load it into a spark DataFrame I receive an error after circa 5 minutes every time.

```
sparkR.session()
spark_data_frame <- createDataFrame(local_r_data_frame, numPartitions=500)
```

The error:

```
 RserveException: eval failed
```

I have tried with up to 10000 paritions and the same error is received after the same amount of processing time.

Comment: This type of error usually happens when driver node goes out of memory. That is unlikely to happen because of converting local dataframe to Spark dataframe. Did you try specifying the schema there?

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I did not know you could specify schema I will research it and try to give it a try